# Import JS partials with webpack and gulp

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I don't understand how the following line of code works:

```
var aScriptName = require('./modules/your-script');
```

I want to split out my JS by using the require statement above with webpack. What I don't understand, is that when I include this multiple times in the script file, my partials do not all consistently load.

My folder structure for my JS looks something like this:

```
-app
---js
-----script.js
-----modules
---------module1.js
---------module2.js
---------module3.js
---------module4.js
```

With this in mind, what I'm trying to do is call the modules like this in script.js:

```
var 1script = require('./modules/module1');
var 2script = require('./modules/module2');
var 3script = require('./modules/module3');
var 4script = require('./modules/module4');
```

A full copy of my webpack is below:

```
var debug = false;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  // entry is already defined in gulpfile.js - leave this line commented out.
  // entry: "/app/js/script.js",
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query  :{
          presets:['es2015']
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "public/javascripts",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    // new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true, mangle: true }),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
};
```

My relevant Gulp script:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('client/js/script.js')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
        .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

What's happening is it's only loading the first 2 includes, then the rest don't render. Is the syntax not correct for including the partials in script.js?

This is my console output after running `gulp scripts`

```
[13:56:14] Starting 'scripts'... [13:56:14] Finished 'scripts' after
3.53 ms [13:56:17] Version: webpack 1.15.0
         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names scripts.min.js  90.4 kB       0  [emitted]  main
```

**EDIT:** Upon further inspection, it does indeed seem that scripts are being piped in correctly - but they don't run. plugging in `console.log("test")`s in the functions contained in the partials don't render - my console is empty.

Why would that be?

**EDIT #2:** The partials is mostly just jQuery code, so they all look something like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery')

$(function() {
  console.log("test 3")
  // jquery code here
});
```

I made 3 test files with just console logs, and all 3 appeared.

Is it because something is conflicting in my functions? Because when it's all my normal code, none of it runs, with no errors in console.

Comment: Don't you have any error when running this?

Comment: @JoseAPL Nope. I will update my answer with output hold on

Comment: where is `console.log("test")` written, and how do you export it?

Comment: that is written in a partial in one of the first lines so something like `$(function() { console.log("test") });` which if I do that in one of the first partials, I can see the message in my console but if I include it in the third or others I don't. I'm trying to export it like the first line of code, or are you referring to something like `module.exports = init;`?

Comment: yes, could you please add a basic part of the first module and the one has is not being logged?

Comment: It's mostly just blocks of jQuery - I tried making 3 test files all with a console log  and what's frustrating is that all 3 showed up in my console...so it's some sort of conflict with each other.

Comment: What is a "partial"?

Comment: the problem is that if you are exporting and assigning to a variable it means that it's a function to be executed or an object of values if you don't do anything with it then nothing will happen, that's why i want to see your code

Comment: partials meaning the snippets I'm pulling in from `require()` - @JoseAPL you want to see the code in my modules?

Comment: @kawnah yes, mostly the exports

Comment: in your EDIT #2, are you trying to make an IIFE? if so it should look like this `(function() { console.log(2);})();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
var aScriptName = require('./modules/your-script');
```

To:

```
import {aScriptName} from './modules/your-script'
```

And everything is working as expected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import